# Reactotron giving "SKIPPED" for response of network calls

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactotron

I was using Reactotron version 1 for logging my network response in my react native app, everything was working fine, recently i changed my Reactotron version to version 2.1.2, and after that i started getting skipped in my response tab in reactotron app.

I didn't change anything in my reactotron setup in my code

```
 if(__DEV__)
     Reactotron
      .configure() // controls connection & communication settings
      .useReactNative()// add all built-in react native plugins
      .use(networking())
      .use(reactotronRedux())
      .connect(); // let's connect!
```

Need help to figure out why it is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which already is fixed on master: [Reactotron Pull Request #837](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/pull/837). Unfortunately they haven't yet released a new npm package, and it looks like they're focusing a major next version instead, so you can either patch your npm package manually or wait for a new release.

Comment: I am still seeing this today.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this api route on localhost, try using the command: `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000`, to change the TCP port attached to your emulator and it will probably work.

Detail, the port 3000 there was just an example, if your api is running on port 3333 for example, then please change the command to `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000`,
The response of the command should be the port number, as shown in the image below.

[image: 1]

Success.